# Python access variable

Tags: python, pygame

Im new to python and im trying something with pygame but dont know how should I do this..

```
def addRect(x, y, width, height, color, surface):
    rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Thats for creating rectangles but my question is how should I access the ractangles I create ? Im trying something like .

```
r1 = addRect(20, 40, 200, 200, (61, 61, 61), screen)
```

But then when I try to move it using

```
r1.move(10,10)
```

I get an error

> r1.move(10,10)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'move'

How should I access it ?  thanks-

Comment: You are not returning the `rect` from the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python functions have a default return value of `None`. Since, you don't have a return statement in your function, it returns `None` which does not have an attribute `move()`.

From [The Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)

> In fact, even functions without a return statement do return a value,
>   albeit a rather boring one. This value is called None (it’s a built-in
>   name).

```
>>> def testFunc(num):
        num += 2

>>> print testFunc(4)
None
```

You need to add a `return` statement to return the `rect` variable.

```
def addRect(x, y, width, height, color, surface):
    rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    return rect
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much PyGame but you could modify addRect -

```
def addRect(x, y, width, height, color, surface):
    rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    return rect # Added this line. Returns the rect object for future use.
```

Then you can make rects and use methods too -

```
rect1 = addRect(20, 40, 200, 200, (61, 61, 61), screen)
rect1.move(10,10)
```

That should work